# Disable 'Ripple' effect of Angular Meterial Stepper component (when clicking on Tab)

Tags: angular, angular-material-6, angular-material-stepper, ripplejs, mat-stepper

I have an app that uses Angular Material Stepper component.

`<mat-horizontal-stepper>`

How can I disable 'ripple' behavior on click by step tabs without CSS-hacks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I assume we are talking about the material2 library as you tagged Angular 6, I will be referencing the Material2 library below.</s>

I looked at the material js library and do not see a stepper.

looking at tab-group.ts as a reference we can look at how the inputs are defined in the constructor... this line specifically accepts disableRipple

```
 inputs: ['color', 'disableRipple'],
```

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/tabs/tab-group.ts

looking at the stepper.ts for comparison, unfortunately, there currently is not an input to disableRipple in the constructor.

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/stepper/stepper.ts

I believe there is no logic to disable ripple on the stepper that I can tell.

- If your preference is to not use CSS hacks, this unfortunately will be a feature request that will need to be submitted.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Actually it is the lib: https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Comment: correct, that is the material 2 library. My links above are accurate to the source for your link. if my answer was satisfactory, please mark it as such. I could use the rep.